# Magento2 - Varnisch - Hard cache problems

Tags: magento2, customer, varnish

We recently released a Magento 2.0.7 webshop. This webshop uses Varnish as Full Page cache.

When a customer visits the homepage, logs in and returns to the homepage there's still a button with 'Log in', instead of 'My acccount'. This is the cached version of the homepage.

Also, some customers should get different prices based on their customer group. After login these customers still see the old prices, after a hard refresh the correct price is shown. This is confusing for a lot of customers.

Is there a solution to these sort of cache-issues?

Comment: Are you using the proper VCL code for Varnish, that was generated inside Magento admin panel?

Comment: Did you [flush the cache?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean)

Comment: @DanielV. yes I did use the VCL code generated by Magento, although I had some issues loading it. I will reload it and check if this solves my issues.

Comment: @SteveJohnson yes I did flush and purge the cache.

Comment: @Silvan - Have you find the solution for this ? Sign In link issue ?

Comment: @ManthanDave no, unfortunately not.

Comment: @Silvan Any solution to this yet? I was thinking whether it might be because you might not be on "production" environment, as Varnish recommends?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to the lastest version of Magento: 2.1.2

There are some problems with localstorage management in Magento 2.0.x

Upgrade to the latest version solved many problems on my side.

From the change log (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.0CE.html and 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.1CE.html) :

- Multi-site cache now shows the correct site’s content.
  ([GITHUB-4556](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4556))
- Varnish cache is no longer disabled on most HTML    requests.
- The default full page cache (FPC) implementation no longer caches
  content with non-HTML Content-Type headers (for example, text/css,
  application/JavaScript), before re-serving this content as text/HTML.
- Cache behavior on checkout now works as expected (the only pages
  uncached belong to the order (products and category of the products).
  (GITHUB-4222)
- Tier pricing now works correctly with full page cache. (GITHUB-5364)